# Non-coconut substitute for coconut cream

Tags: substitutions, coconut

I'm planning on cooking a Massaman curry but for someone who really dislikes the taste of coconut. What would a good substitute be? I'm thinking of just using cream instead - do you think that would work well?

Comment: Do you know that they dislike curry that contains coconut milk? A lot of people who really don't like coconut are fine with curry; the flavor is a lot more subtle and there's no texture to possibly dislike as there is with actual coconut.

Answer (score 0):

I would use cream as well. It's very similar in structure, thus they both have the title cream.

Answer (score 0):

It's not Massaman without coconut milk. Massaman I have had this in the south of Thailand and usually not too thick with coconut milk, it is a carrier of the other flavors.